# DataGridTemplateColumn read textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid with 3 DataGridTemplateColumn at the end:
[image]

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="464" Margin="90,97,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="840" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Codice" Binding="{Binding Codice}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Descrizione" Binding="{Binding Descrizione}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Giacenza" Binding="{Binding Giacenza}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="In Ordine" Binding="{Binding In Ordine}" />

    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Button Click="Togli_Click">-</Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBox Width="25" x:Name="txtQTA">0</TextBox>
       </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Click="Aggiungi_Click">+</Button>
        </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I would like that if I click on "+" or "-" the textbox "txtQTA" increments or decrements. I don't reach to find the textbox in the button click.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution I found:

```
private void Aggiungi_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txt = FindVisualChildByName<TextBox>(dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dataGrid.SelectedIndex) as DataGridRow, "txtQTA", dataGrid.SelectedIndex);
            txt.Text = "Writing";
        }
        public T FindVisualChildByName<T>(DependencyObject parent, string name, int nRiga) where T : DependencyObject
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)



            {

                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

                string controlName = child.GetValue(Control.NameProperty) as string;

                if (controlName == name)

                {

                    return child as T;

                }

                else

                {

                    T result = FindVisualChildByName<T>(child, name, nRiga);

                    if (result != null)

                        return result;

                }

            }

            return null;

        }
```